# Microsoft Graph /me not working for Personal Account

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on implementing OneDrive APIs,though for developer account able to get user detail but while trying login through personal account or other account rather developer account,I am getting following response :

```
protocol=http/1.1, 
code=401, 
message=Unauthorized, 
url=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

I have given all of the Application as well as Delegated permissions in the Azure developer console.

Permissions that were set in Azure developer console:
[image: Permissions]

```java
com.squareup.okhttp.Request request = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder() 
  .url("graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me") 
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken) 
  .build(); 
try {   
   response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute(); 
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, response.toString()); // Do something with the response. 
} 
catch (IOException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
return response;
```

Comment: Please provide a code example of how you make the request.

Comment: com.squareup.okhttp.Request request = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder()
                .url("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .build();

        try {
            response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, response.toString());                    // Do something with the response.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

Comment: also getting access token

Comment: The Authorization part looks Ok.. Maybe try to get the access token and test it making some requests to the API from Postman (this is a nice app to play with REST API requests)

Comment: You can drop all of the "Application" scopes, they are not applicable to personal accounts. You can also drop any "Delegated" scopes that require Admin Consent as they are _also_ not applicable to personal accounts.

Comment: How are you obtaining the token? And please provide a sample token that isn't working. That will shed a lot of light on what is going on.

Comment: Not able to paste sample token over comment as it is exceeding character length.
Can you please suggest some possible solution,In fact https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive this api is working for personal account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a good quick start and a 30 min walk through tutorial here that would be useful to walk through to understand the permissions side and delegated authentication

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/android

For a user delegated flow, you do not need the application permissions you have consented there. To authenticate /me you only require `User.Read` as per docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You can use https://jwt.ms/ and take the access token to validate that the scope is in the token too.